# Django. Sort objects in a chain

Tags: python, django

I set up `sorting related` to the object manager. I have `views.py`

```
def Objects(request):
    Objects_1 = car_type_1.objects.filter(manager_id='1', is_published=True)
    Objects_2 = car_type_2.objects.filter(manager_id='1', is_published=True)
    Objects_3 = car_type_3.objects.filter(manager_id='1', is_published=True)
    queryset_list = list(chain(Objects_1, Objects_2, Objects_3))
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 6)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paged_listings = paginator.get_page(page)
    context = {'listings': paged_listings}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

As a result, I get a page with objects. Responsible `manager id 1` for all objects.

Everything is sorted correctly on the page. Showing `manager id 1` objects. But, they are shown, one by one.
First all from the group `car_type_1`, then the group `car_type_2` and `car_type_3`.

Question. How to make objects `sorted by price` from all groups?

**Thank!**

Comment: It looks like "strange" modeling, why do you have three different models for cars? Why not add a `type` field that specifies what the type of the car is?

Comment: Willem Van Onsem, hello! Yes, I agree, it’s strange. Different types, these are bodies hatchback, sedan, etc...
Different models are needed to more easily describe an object. I see it this way, perhaps primitively. Essentially, you need to sort the lists in a chain.

Comment: the only way you can do that is at the Django/Python level then. So that means loading all `car_type_1`s, `car_type_2`s, etc. and then sort these. For small databases that is reasonable. For larger ones, this will easily yield the server unresponsive. That is *the* reason why sorting/filtering/... is usually done at the db level.

Comment: Thank! I get it. I thought about `sort`. The base will be small, maximum 200 records of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the items in the list with `sorted(..)`:

```
from operator import attrgetter

def objects(request):
    objs1 = car_type_1.objects.filter(manager_id='1', is_published=True)
    objs2 = car_type_2.objects.filter(manager_id='1', is_published=True)
    objs3 = car_type_3.objects.filter(manager_id='1', is_published=True)
    items = sorted(chain(objs1, objs2, objs3), key=attrgetter('price'))
    paginator = Paginator(items, 6)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paged_listings = paginator.get_page(page)
    context = {'listings': paged_listings}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

But the above is *not* efficient if you need to sort huge amounts of data, since this will result in fetching all objects into memory and sorting these. Whereas a database usually is optimized to do the sorting on a limited result set.

It might be better to reconsider your design, and merge the three `car_type_i`s into a single model.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem, as always, you're right on target! Thank you, it works beautifully!